# R / POSIX control result format (sec, min, hr)

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I'm working with some `POSIXct` objects in R and was wondering how to control the format of the answers.

```
train$targetVar1 <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(as.character(string1),tz="UTC") - as.POSIXct(as.character(string2),tz="UTC"))
```

The answers seem to pop up as `sec`, `min` and `hr` in no obvious relationship to the data.

I looked at using `POSIXlt` as the help file makes it sound like `lt` objects create a vector for each time scale, but can't figure out how to access the vectors using the various methods like :

```
> posixObj1 <- as.POSIXlt("2012-12-12 12:00:00")
> posixObj1$sec
[1] 0
> posixObj1$min
[1] 0
> posixObj1$hour
[1] 12

> x <- as.POSIXlt("2012-12-12")
> x
[1] "2012-12-12"
> format(x, "%s")
[1] ""
```

Any suggestions?

Note: I'm running R 2.15.1 on a windows 7 machine.

Comment: Which result do you expect for your example `as.POSIXlt("2012-12-12")`?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: for posixObj1$sec, I'd expect the # of seconds since 1-1-1970.

Comment: This works for me on R-2.15.2 (perhaps this is a bug in 2.15.1?).  Also, the `POSIXlt` hour element is named `hour`, not `hr`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: thanks for pointing that out.  When I switch to hour it appears that the vectors are just holding the time pieces.  I assumed they were converting the # of seconds to minutes, hours, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` objects are very different. You can see this by using `dput`:

```
dput(Sys.time())
structure(1356100378.30553, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))

dput(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))
structure(list(sec = 13.2815599441528, min = 33L, hour = 14L, 
    mday = 21L, mon = 11L, year = 112L, wday = 5L, yday = 355L, 
    isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
), tzone = c("", "GMT", "BST"))
```

`POSIXct` is the one which records the seconds since the UNIX epoch, and you can get these by using `as.numeric` or `unclass`:

```
as.numeric(Sys.time())
[1] 1356100510
unclass(Sys.time())
[1] 1356100516
```

Note that the difference in the results is due to me taking 6 seconds to call the second command.

As for your original problem, `-.POSIXt` ultimately calls `difftime` which has a default `units` parameter as `auto`. This means that the output units will depend on the size of the difference. To get consistency, call `difftime` directly:

```
difftime(as.POSIXct(as.character(string1),tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct(as.character(string2),tz="UTC")), units="secs")
```

Comment: There is also the usefull `units(x) <- value` for `difftime` objects.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `format`:

```
x <- as.POSIXlt("2012-12-12")

format(x, "%s")    
[1] "1355266800"
```

The argument `"%s"` indicates seconds.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  See edit to question.  I just get 2 quotes with nothing between them.